# How to find and download a missing plugin?

Tags: rhythmbox, plugins, internet-radio

I tried to add a radio station to the radio player of Rhythmbox, so I clicked "add" and copied the [URL](http://www.mosaiquefm.net/fr/index/a/Player) but it won't play when I click on "play".
A window comes in the first place searching for a plug-in then it tells me (something like) that:

> python 2.7 is missing a plug-in type text html decoder

When I open the properties of the radio added it tells:

> Your Gstreamer installation is missing a plug-in.

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL is just a real website with some flash based redirection to the real URL:

http://radio.mosaiquefm.net:8000/mosalive

When you paste this, it will work.

Comment: Thanks a lot...
It worked ! but can you explain how you found the link if possible ? ^^

Comment: I just pasted your URL into a web browser, then looked at the source of the website it loaded, scrolled down and found out. (I don't speak french at all)

Comment: Thanks a lot again, you don't need to speak french :)